# Increase perfomance of site

Tags: caching

I am using [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) in header.

The setup is Drupal 7.35 + Oracle + Apache2. Theses are all the items which takes more execution time.

How can I cache menu items path and all Js and CSS files.

Comment: Go Through http://colans.net/blog/drupal-7-performance-optimization-options-and-checklist

Comment: "How can I cache menu items path" - Can you explain in more detail what you mean by this?